# box isn't appearing or moving on JPanel.. Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, animation, jpanel

I am trying to create this box on my panel 1 of Java but nothing is showing up on the screen :/ what is the problem? Sorry I am new to java animation and its so hard! Also, I want the box to only appear and move on the first panel not the second.. Here are my codes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class frog extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame= new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Hungry");
    JPanel panel2=new JPanel();
    JTextField t;
    Timer tm= new Timer(5, this);
    int x=0, velX=2;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(100,10,30,40);
        g.fillRect(x,10,20,10);
        tm.start();
    }
    JLabel l= new JLabel("Good");
    frog(){
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        t= new JTextField("Frog is hungry",10);
        panel2.add(t);
        panel2.add(button);
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel2,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frog f= new frog();

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        t.setText("Now he is full");
        x=x+velX;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: While I scratch my head over your code, go have a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to better understand how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's stop for a minute and have a look at what you've done.

You've created a class which extends from `JPanel`

```
public class Frog extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

Okay. You've overridden `paintComponent` to do some custom painting

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(100, 10, 30, 40);
    g.fillRect(x, 10, 20, 10);
    tm.start();
}
```

Okay, there's some issues here, but lets keep going. In the panel's constructor, you've create two new panels, you've added this two panels to a `JFrame` and made it visible

```
Frog() {
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    t = new JTextField("Frog is hungry", 10);
    panel2.add(t);
    panel2.add(button);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

But wait, what about the `Frog` panel that never gets added to anything, so how is it suppose to be displayed?

Also, the constructor has some very nasty side effects, put aside the non-associated panels, it creates a frame when ever it's called, this really a bad idea.

## Basic OO

With OO, you want to limit the functionality of any object to a single responsibility, the `Frog` panel has no responsibility creating the additional panels (they add no functionality to the `Frog` panel) or making a frame, it's responsibility is to paint and animate the frog, nothing else.

```
public class FrogPane extends JPanel {

    private Timer timer;
    int x = 0, velX = 2;

    public FrogPane() {
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                            x = x + velX;
                                            repaint();
                                        }
                                    });
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawRect(100, 10, 30, 40);
        g2d.fillRect(x, 10, 20, 10);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Okay, so the `FrogPane` is pretty basic, it paints a representation of the frog and updates the position via the use of a `Timer`.  Notice that the `Timer` is NOT started in the `paintComponent`, `paintComponent` can be called for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control, so don't do anything within it which might change the state of the component or which you are relying on to perform some secondary task

The next thing we need to do is to display it and have some way to start it

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                FrogPane frogPane = new FrogPane();

                JTextField t = new JTextField("Frog is hungry", 10);
                JButton button = new JButton("Hungry");

                JPanel actionPane = new JPanel();
                actionPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                actionPane.add(t);
                actionPane.add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        t.setText("Run frog run");
                        frogPane.start();
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(frogPane);
                frame.add(actionPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, your next question is going to be able how to manage state between different classes, which suggest to me that you need to go away and do some more research into [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and better understand the concept of separation of responsibilities.  The basic answer is, you use a model.

Comment: OMG thank u so much. Really helped me understand stuff. Since i am new to java gui programming, I will surely come across some problems. Hope you can continue helping me! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the animation for the `frog` class, but you are not adding a `frog` panel to your `JFrame`. Your first panel is a plain `Jpanel`, which doesn't have the associated `paintComponent` override.

You should:

1. Remove the line

   ```
   JPanel panel=new JPanel();
   ```
2. Instead of

   ```
   panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
   ```

   use

   ```
   this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
   ```
3. Instead of

   ```
   frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```

   use

   ```
   frame.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```

Now the first panel will be the currently created `frog`, and you should be able to see the animation.

### Notes:

- Please mind the Java language conventions. A class name should start with a capital letter (`Frog` rather than `frog`).
- Note that your `actionPerformed` is being used by both the timer and the button. Are you sure that this is what you wanted? Also, I think it's unlikely that you want to start the timer every time the panel is repainted.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry i didn't quite understand.. How do I declare the panel then? I am so sorry for sounding daft but java gui is this new thing for me and its confusing..

Comment: @thefeels I gave you three things that you have to change in your source. You don't need to declare the panel as you are *inside* the panel and the `this` reference is your panel.